# AutoComplete ComboBox with ControlsFX triggers auto completion when selecting value with mouse

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I have a simple `ComboBox` that I've used ControlsFX to make auto-completing. This works perfectly except for one annoying flaw:  When the user uses the dropdown to select an item with the mouse, the autocomplete window opens up, essentially offering matching suggestions to the user.

The desired behavior is for the selection of a value with the mouse to close the popup altogether.

The code below will demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields;

public class AutoCompleteComboBox extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Create a standard ComboBox
        ComboBox<Person> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        // Sample items
        ObservableList<Person> people = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        people.addAll(
                new Person("William", 34),
                new Person("Ashley", 12),
                new Person("Marvin", 63),
                new Person("Suresh", 18),
                new Person("Jackson", 24)
        );
        comboBox.setItems(people);

        // Add StringConverter
        comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Person>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Person person) {
                return (person == null ? null : person.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public Person fromString(String string) {
                for (Person person : comboBox.getItems()) {
                    if (person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
                        return person;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

        // Make the ComboBox autocomplete using ControlsFX
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(comboBox.getEditor(), comboBox.getItems());

        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

So typing into the editor and selecting a value with the keyboard works fine. But if you click the arrow to open the dropdown and select a value that way, you can see the issue (it essentially forces the user to select a value twice).

How would I go about preventing this behavior?

Comment: It looks like a bug due to the text changing.

Comment: I agree; any ideas for a workaround? I am not very familiar with the ControlsFX internal API.

Comment: @Zephyr Did you find a solution please?